# How to Check the Version of my gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, centos7, g++4.8

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/locale:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/iomanip:43,
                 from [...omitted by myself as it is irrelevant]
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/locale_facets_nonio.h:59:39: error: ‘locale’ has not been declared
     struct __timepunct_cache : public locale::facet
```

Above is the first error in my build log.

I didn't try to compile glibc/gcc myself, and I installed them via yum.

One fishy thing I found is:

```
$ ll /usr/include/c++/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root root 4096 Dec 17 14:16 4.8.2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    5 Dec 17 14:16 4.8.5 -> 4.8.2
$
```

And yum showed only 1 version of gcc:

```
$ yum info gcc-c++
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.uhost.hk
 * epel: mirrors.hustunique.com
 * extras: centos.uhost.hk
 * updates: centos.uhost.hk
Installed Packages
Name        : gcc-c++
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 4.8.5
Release     : 4.el7
Size        : 16 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : base
Summary     : C++ support for GCC
URL         : http://gcc.gnu.org
License     : GPLv3+ and GPLv3+ with exceptions and GPLv2+ with exceptions and LGPLv2+ and BSD
Description : This package adds C++ support to the GNU Compiler Collection.
            : It includes support for most of the current C++ specification,
            : including templates and exception handling.
```

Any idea how to verify the headers in /usr/include/c++/4.8.2 is indeed from 4.8.5 package?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.  I think probably glibc is irrelevant but here is the info:

```
$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Comment: Are you asking about glibc or gcc? The question title disagrees with the actual question. Make your mind up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The symlink to the `4.8.2` directory is nothing to worry about, it's normal for the libstdc++ headers on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and therefore CentOS) to be arranged like that.

`gcc --version` will tell you the version of the `gcc` executable in your path.

`rpm -q libstdc++-devel` will tell you the version of the package that owns the C++ standard library headers.

`rpm -ql libstdc++-devel` will list the files installed by that package, which will include the files under `/usr/include/c++/4.8.2`

`rpm --verify libstdc++-devel` will check that you haven't messed up the C++ headers by replacing them with something else.

The error is more concerning, that implies you have messed *something* up. My guess would be it's in the `from [...omitted by myself as it is irrelevant]` part, which may actually be very relevant. `std::locale` should be declared in `<bits/locale_classes.h>` which is included before `<bits/locale_facets_nonio.h>`, so if it wasn't declared my guess is that you have some header that defines `_LOCALE_CLASSES_H` and prevents the standard library header from being read. Do **not** define include guards that start with underscores, they are [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Very useful info.  Tho once I commented out #include <iomanip> (which include <locale>) and one line of code that uses std::setfill(), above error goes away.  Tho there are some errors unrelated to <locale>.  Not sure whether because of those error, gcc confused and produced the false positive error above.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. There should be no errors from including standard headers.

Comment: how to check the maximum C version supported by my gcc?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB that is a different question, please don't use comments on other people's questions to ask something different. You should read the docs that come with your version of gcc to find out.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure but below is more information

[Stackoverflow: version of libc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163138/how-do-i-find-what-version-of-libc-my-application-links-to)

```
$ /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
GNU C Library (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6) stable release version 2.19, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.8.2.
Compiled on a Linux 3.13.9 system on 2014-04-12.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eglibc/+bugs>.
mandar@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: Despite the confusing title, the question has nothing to do with glibc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Linux you can try

```
 ldd --version
```

Comment: I've edited your answer a little bit. The OP is calling `yum`, which is a package manager for Linux so the "if you are using Linux" was unnecessary. I also added a sample output of the command.

Comment: Despite the confusing title, the question has nothing to do with glibc.